# highcharts: disable only a single element in legend so it cannot be clicked

Tags: plot, legend, highcharts

I was wondering is it possible to prevent only a one element in plot legend from disabling/enabling. Let's say I have three categories in my legend: 'car1', 'car2', 'car3'. I would like to show/hide only 'car2' and 'car3', while 'car1' is shown all the time.

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it's always a certain series that you want to disable show/hide, then within the [legendItemClick](http://www.highcharts.com/ref/#plotOptions-series-events--legendItemClick) return false for that series.

For example:

```
plotOptions: {
        series: {
            events: {
                legendItemClick: function(event) {
                    return !(this.name == 'car1');
                }
            }
        }
    },
```